# Can I convert a webpage created with Dreamweaver to Webmatrix project?

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, dreamweaver, webmatrix

Database of the website was created in WAMP (phpMyAdmin) and I need the database and the webpage in Webmatrix. Is there a possible solution or I need to re-write the webpage all over again?
I wouldn't do this, but I have to do it for my school project, because the teacher won't accept the web site in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Yes; you can use MySQL from .Net.  What have you tried? What problem did you have?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using DW templates then your teacher wouldn't know if you used DW or a text editor to create your site.

If you are using templates then these can be removed before submitting your work. From the menu select Modify -> templates -> Remove template markup

You might want to backup your files before doing this.

Comment: The only problem I have is that the Webmatrix isn't reading my database and the website isn't fully functional.